# Cannot get wpdb data (Error in a simple fuction)

Tags: plugins, functions, mysql, wpdb

I'm using Cryto Plugin and want to get coin price data from plugin db.
[image]

For easy practice, I'm trying to get BTC data.

```
<?php function get_coin_price($coin_symbol) {
  global $wpdb;

  $coin_price = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT price FROM {$wpdb->prefix}cmc_coins_v2 WHERE symbol = '%s'", $coin_symbol));

  return $coin_price;
}?>
```

And if I want to get BTC price, I use this code.

```
<?php get_coin_price(BTC); ?>
```

However I'm getting this error 
 **"Use of undefined constant BTC - assumed 'BTC' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"** 
 Is there a problem in data type? or maybe am I not using $wpdb->get_var or wpdb->prepare correctly?

Comment: All variables in PHP begin with a `$`, and string values need to be encapsulated in quotation marks. Since the `BTC` in `get_coin_price(BTC)` has neither of these attributes, PHP believes it to be a constant. As this question is regarding PHP syntax rather than WordPress or it's APIs, it may be considered off-topic for our stack

Comment: Hey @bosco, thanks for the answer and you are right in a way. However this question contains some Wordpress terms like $wpdb or get_var function so I can not ask this  questions on php forum or API forum. I hope you understand.

Comment: I certainly get where you're coming from! But Stack Exchange sites' scopes are much more defined than traditional web communities - per [this stack's definition](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), questions here must detail a problem specifically regarding the WordPress software and/or it's APIs. Questions regarding general PHP syntax and errors are still specific to PHP, even when that code is used within a WordPress site - Stack Overflow is a more appropriate site for such things. In this case you weren't sure of the root cause - no harm no foul :)

Comment: The question will likely remain closed for the reason that the problem and solution are not pertinent to WordPress itself (and thus it's broader development community) - but I am glad that you found a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about changing BTC to a string
`<?php get_coin_price('BTC'); ?>`

Comment: Wow, it worked! Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

should be a comment but can't.
your error just says that in `<?php get_coin_price(BTC); ?>`  BTC is considered a variable but is not defined and compiler assume the variable as a string, it doesn't seems to crash your script, but still should be used like so `<?php get_coin_price("BTC"); ?>`

Comment: Thanks! This worked too. Thank you @safir